# How to make a custom method in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Currently, I'm learning about Spring Data JPA, and I found that I need to create a custom interface to make a custom methods. I wonder if someone can explain to me why this is so. Let's say I have entity `User` with fields: `userId` and `name`. Also, I have `UserRepository`:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {...}
```

I found that I need to make new interface - `UserRepositoryCustom` where I should make custom abstract methods. Also, after that, I found that I need to make class `UserRepositoryImpl` which implements `UserRepositoryCustom`. Let's take a look at the code I made:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<User> findUserByName(String name) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT em.* FROM User em " +
                "WHERE em.name = ?1", User.class);
        query.setParameter(1, name);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Can you please explain why I need `UserRepositoryCustom` and `UserRepositoryImpl` in foreground, And why do I need `EntityManager` and `@PersistenceContext` above it? Every piece of information is of great importance to me, because that way I will be able to extract what is most important for me, which is to understand.

I found this code, which is working fine, online, but I need to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't **need** to do this. The direct equivalent would be a method in your `UserRepository` interface defined as `List<User> findByName(String name)`. You can also use JPA named queries, the `@Query` annotation, etc.

The usage of additional interfaces and implementation classes is intended for advanced use cases that are not (easily) possible in the queries Spring Data JPA generates for you based on method names, annotations, etc. It is not intended for easy use cases like the query you show.

And the reason why, is because that is how Spring Data JPA is designed. I highly recommend you read the full [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/). You'll notice that the solution in your question is [just a minor part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) of the documentation, which makes clear that this is an escape hatch, not the primary way of using Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Yes, I understand that for such a simple method I don't need such an implementation, but my main question is in what situations (for example) should I have a new interface with such an implementation. What you mean under "advanced use cases that are not possible in the queries Spring Data JPA generates for you based on method names". Sorry for asking this kind of question, I'm just trying to understand it. Edit: I've read your edit, thank you.

Comment: @drogiraniProgramer In the past I have used it to dynamically generate and execute a complex query that used PostgreSQL JSONB operators (where the exact query depended on the parameters passed in). That is just not possible with the queries derived from method names or annotations. I recommend only using it if the other ways offered by Spring Data JPA simply don't work.